# finding the 3rd highest salary in mysql without limit

Tags: mysql

i have been trying to find the 3rd highest salary of a table without using limit.

In case of 2nd highest salary i use

`SELECT salary FROM table WHERE salary < ( SELECT MAX( salary )  order by salary desc`

to find the 3rd highest with limit i use

`select salary from one order by salary desc limit 3,1`

now how to find nth salary without using limit?

Comment: What's the problem with `LIMIT`? Why avoid the very clause that does what you need?

Comment: no problem is there using limit.but if it can be done with calculation for any nth row then it would be great.

Comment: y downvotes?does this query makes no sense?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this Query,

```
   SELECT *
   FROM one one1
   WHERE ( 3 ) = ( SELECT COUNT( one2.salary )
                   FROM one one2
                   WHERE one2.salary >= one1.salary
                 )
```

Here **WHERE ( n )** yo can put any number to return that highest salary.

Check this <kbd>**[Demo SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9ff5a/3/0)**</kbd>

Comment: but its taking way more time then the one using LIMIT

Comment: Care to expain what did you do?

Comment: This query will be fail if there are duplicate records , for example if two employees have same salary then it will return 0 rows.

Comment: Use N-1 for Nth highest salary. Its important to understand why the `... WHERE (N-1) = ( query )...` works. The Subquery is a `correlated` because its `WHERE` clause uses `one1.salary` from main query. The subquery is evaluated each time main query scans over a row. Example, to find 3rd largest salary from (800, 1000, 700, 750), the subquery for 1st row would be `...WHERE one2.salary > 800` which returns `0` as there is no sal higher than 800. For 4th salary value (750) `... WHERE one2.salary > 750` returns 2 which equals N-1 from main query, hence this row is the overall answer.

Comment: It's not going to work, if you have duplicate salaries.

Answer (score 3):

how about doing it with variables? *just wondering why you don't want to use `LIMIT`*.

```
SELECT salary
FROM
(
  SELECT @rn := @rn + 1 rn,
       a.salary
  FROM tableName a, (SELECT @rn := 0) b
  ORDER BY salary DESC
) sub
WHERE sub.rn = 3
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f08c1/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo *not filtered*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f08c1/2)

Comment: it worked bro. can u plz xplain/elaborate the query.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE (3) = (
               SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(t2.Salary))
               FROM table t2
               WHERE t2.Salary >= t1.Salary
               );
```

Comment: Can you explain how the count works in the above condition for 1 - highest 3 - 3rd highest got confused.