# How to find the nth salary in mysql without using LIMIT

Tags: mysql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I am trying to find variuos ways to find the solution og this problem.
I understood most of them but one solution that I found going though all the sites and answers on stackoverflow is [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22854687/finding-the-3rd-highest-salary-in-mysql-without-limit)

```
SELECT *
FROM one one1
WHERE ( 3 ) = ( SELECT COUNT( one2.salary )
               FROM one one2
               WHERE one2.salary >= one1.salary
             )
```

My problem is I do not understand how is this working I tried to find explanation online but could not find anywhere I even tried to break it douwn on paper I understand it is using correlated subquery but nothing more than that I could understand.

So , please could someone explain to me step by step how it works with and example ??

Comment: ok but does it work as u need?

Comment: and what's the problem with using LIMIT clause?

Comment: Please spell out your understanding of ***what*** exactly is counted by the sub-query.  Add it to your question by using [Edit]).

Comment: @ George no problem , but just trying to explore other options .
@PM 77 I am not sure what it is doing

Comment: If you cannot read a simple query - then you need more training in basic SQL.  I suggest to go through [SQL Zoo](https://sqlzoo.net/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [finding the 3rd highest salary in mysql without limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22854687/finding-the-3rd-highest-salary-in-mysql-without-limit)